# Monitorizar red con SNMP y Java

Tags: java

Estoy practicando sobre el uso de SNMP para monitorizar redes. Tomando como base el código de https://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/java/snmp/create-snmp-client-in-java-using-snmp4j/ que monitoriza un dispositivo de solo una IP prefijada, lo estoy modificando para que mediante un bucle "for" vaya recorriendo todas las IP de un rango y haga solicitudes GET de unas OIDs. Todo va bien si en las IP realmente se encuentra un dispositivo con SNMP activo pero si la IP está vacía o el dispositivo no tiene activo SNMP se detiene con una excepción. He intentado sin éxito capturar la excepción y redirigir el flujo de programa para que continue buscando en la siguiente IP del bucle.

El programa cae en el método getAsStrint con una esperable java.lang.NullPointerException. He probado try catch para capturar la excepción y intentar que siga el flujo sin que funcione.

```
public class SNMPManager {

Snmp snmp = null;
address = null;

/**
* Constructor
*
* @param add
*/
public SNMPManager(String add) {
 address = add;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
/**
* Port 161 is used for Read and Other operations
* Port 162 is used for the trap generation
*/


for (int i = 37; i < 40; i++) {

    System.out.println("ip x.x.x." + i);
    SNMPManager client = new SNMPManager("udp:192.168.1." + i + "/161");
    //SNMPManager client = new SNMPManager("udp:192.168.1.37/161");
    client.start();
    /**
    * OID - .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 => SysDec
    * OID - .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0 => SysName
    * => MIB explorer will be usefull here, as discussed in previous article
    */

    String sysDescr = client.getAsString(new OID(".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0"));
    System.out.println(".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0" + " - SysName: " + sysDescr);

    String sysDescr2 = client.getAsString(new OID(".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0"));
    System.out.println(".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0" + " - SysDec: " + sysDescr2);
 }
}

/**
* Start the Snmp session. If you forget the listen() method you will   not
* get any answers because the communication is asynchronous
* and the listen() method listens for answers.
*
* @throws IOException
*/
private void start() throws IOException {
 TransportMapping transport = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping();
 snmp = new Snmp(transport);
// Do not forget this line!
transport.listen();
}

/**
 * Method which takes a single OID and returns the response from the agent as a String.
 *
 * @param oid
 * @return
 * @throws IOException
 */
 public String getAsString(OID oid) throws IOException {
  ResponseEvent event = get(new OID[]{oid});
  return event.getResponse().get(0).getVariable().toString();
 }

/**
* This method is capable of handling multiple OIDs
*
* @param oids
* @return
* @throws IOException
*/
public ResponseEvent get(OID oids[]) throws IOException {
  PDU pdu = new PDU();
  for (OID oid : oids) {
     pdu.add(new VariableBinding(oid));
  }
  pdu.setType(PDU.GET);
  ResponseEvent event = snmp.send(pdu, getTarget(), null);
  if (event != null) {
    return event;
  }
  throw new RuntimeException("GET timed out");
  }

/**
* This method returns a Target, which contains information about
* where the data should be fetched and how.
*
* @return
*/
private Target getTarget() {
  Address targetAddress = GenericAddress.parse(address);
  CommunityTarget target = new CommunityTarget();
  target.setCommunity(new OctetString("public"));
  target.setAddress(targetAddress);
  target.setRetries(2);
  target.setTimeout(1500);
  target.setVersion(SnmpConstants.version2c);
  return target;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

encontré una manera de solucionarlo cambiando la captura de IOExcepception por Exception en el método getAstring.

```
public String getAsString(OID oid){

    ResponseEvent event = null;
    try {
        event = get(new OID[]{oid});
        return event.getResponse().get(0).getVariable().toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("IP no SNMP");
    }
    return "ERROR";

}
```